# What is the difference between ALM with TFS and ALM with Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, alm

Is there a difference between Application Life Cycle Management (ALM) with Team Foundation Server (TFS) and ALM with Visual Studio?
What are the difference?
I am a .Net developer I work on C#, ASP.Net, ASP.Net MVC, WCF and SharePoint. If I've a to learn ALM what should I learn ALM with TFS or VS.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team Foundation Server is the ALM server.  It ships with a web client and a client experience within the Visual Studio development environment.  So, TFS is the server and VS is a client.

There is also a cloud instance of TFS that you can signup for at [visualstudio.com](http://www.visualstudio.com/).  It's free for up to five uses so that would be the easiest path for you to get familiar with the ALM offering.